# datacursormode: spurious MouseMotion event processing when UpdateFcn takes time to return

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using `DATACURSORMODE` in Matlab 8.1.0.604 (R2013a) on Mac OS 10.11.6 (El Capitan).

In the simple example below, the data cursor only moves when a new location is *clicked*, not when the mouse is merely moved.  This is exactly the behaviour I want. However, in my code I get a different behaviour: after the first click, the cursor moves whenever the mouse just moves, until I subsequently double-click. I did not knowingly ask for this latter behaviour and do not want it.

The key difference seems to be that my `UpdateFcn` callback code takes *time* to complete (and let's assume it always will: my callback is intended to perform fairly complex actions, and is already as vectorized and optimized as it can get).  This is emulated by the `pause` statement in the example below, which should hopefully replicate the problem if uncommented (might have to fiddle with the duration, depending on platform/setup).

In `datacursormode.m` the "UNDOCUMENTED FUNCTIONALITY" comments mention that *both* `MouseMotion` and `ButtonDown` events are thrown by a data cursor mode object.  This is clearly not the full story, because by default there's no response to mouse motion alone, but *something* happens, presumably due to the delay, to make it do so.

So my question is:  is this cursor-moving-on-mouse-motion-until-you-doubleclick a known feature/mode,  or just unintended "undefined behaviour" as a side effect of the delay? In either case, how can I (programmatically) prevent it from happening, assuming I can't actually speed up the callback code?

```
function demo

fig = 1;
figure(fig), close, figure(fig)  % ensure virgin figure
image
h = datacursormode(fig);
datacursormode(fig, 'on')
set(h, 'UpdateFcn', @callback)

function txt = callback(cbo, event)
% pause(0.1) % uncomment this line (and/or lengthen the delay as necessary) to replicate the problem 
txt = evalc('cbo,event,disp(get(event))');
```

Comment: Keep adding portions that are similar to your original code until it reproduces the desired behavior. Very few people will want to sit here and play code darts to figure out what's wrong for you.

Comment: I would suggest you, starting from your "complex code", keep removing portions of code just until the problem disappears. If some parts are crucial to the flow of the program and cannot be removed, then replace them with "dummy code". Eventually you will reach a point when you take away a certain code snippet, the problem will disappear. Then you  know the code snippet you just took away must be the direct cause of the problem.

Comment: @excaza Neither approach would have helped, it turns out, because there was no specific step in my code that caused the problem.  Rather, it was just time taken.   I've updated the example and the problem should now hopefully be replicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an edited version of [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306647/will)'s solution that works nicely.  The StartDelay value is critical: <=6ms fails to solve the mouse motion problem.  7ms solves it most of the time, but occasionally lapses. 10ms seems to work fairly reliably (except the very first time in a given new Matlab session, when things are slow to wake up). Typical Matlab implementation flakiness...

```
function demo

fig = 100;
figure(fig), close, figure(fig)  % ensure virgin figure
img = image;
EnableDataCursor(img)



function EnableDataCursor(img)

ax = get(img, 'parent');
fig = get(ax, 'parent');
dcm = datacursormode(fig);
datacursormode(fig, 'on')

set(dcm, 'UpdateFcn', @CursorModeCallback)
setappdata(img, 'CursorModeObject', dcm);
setappdata(img, 'Timer', timer('StartDelay', 0.010, 'TimerFcn', @TimerCallback));
setappdata(img, 'LastText', 'Initial text');



function txt = CursorModeCallback(cbo, event)

img = get(event, 'Target');
t = getappdata(img, 'Timer');
if strcmp(get(t, 'Running'), 'off') % If we have already asked for an updated tooltip and haven't got one yet then don't ask for another one
    txt = 'updating...';
    set(t, 'UserData', {cbo, event}); % Store the data needed by the slow callback to generate the tooltip
    start(t); % Ask the timer to generate new text
else
    txt = getappdata(img, 'LastText'); % Display the most recently generated text in the tooltip
end



function TimerCallback(t, varargin)

ud = get(t, 'UserData');
[cbo, event] = deal(ud{:});
img = get(event, 'Target');

pause(1) % numbercrunch, numbercrunch, numbercrunch

txt = num2str(get(event, 'Position'));
if ~isequal(txt, getappdata(img, 'LastText'))
    setappdata(img, 'LastText', txt); % Store the latest text
    updateDataCursors(getappdata(img, 'CursorModeObject')); % Update the cursor so the text is displayed
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't actually reproduce your problem on R2012a or R2016a on Windows, but it sounds like on your system MATLAB is failing to catch the `ButtonUp` event when you click. The reason `MouseMotion` events are processed is because you should be able to drag the cursor when you have the mouse button held down.

Assuming that it is indeed the slow response of the `UpdateFcn` that causes this, you may be able to resolve this by triggering the slow part in an asynchronous operation which then triggers another update when it is done. The most universal form of this, I think, is to use a `timer` with a very short `StartDelay`. In the example below I've used `appdata` to share handles between the `datacursormode` object and the timer, but you could approach this in many different ways in your specific implementation.

```
function demo

fig = 1;
figure(fig), close, figure(fig)  % ensure virgin figure
image
h = datacursormode(fig);
datacursormode(fig, 'on')
set(h, 'UpdateFcn', @cursormodecallback)
setappdata(fig, 'cursormode',h);
setappdata(fig, 'timer',timer('StartDelay',0.001, 'TimerFcn',@timercallback));
setappdata(fig, 'lasttxt','Initial text');

function txt = cursormodecallback(cbo, event)

txt = getappdata(1,'lasttxt'); % Display the most recently generated text in the tooltip
t = getappdata(1,'timer');
if strcmp(get(t,'Running'),'off') % If we have already asked for an updated tooltip and haven't got one yet then don't ask for another one
    set(t, 'UserData',{cbo,event}); % Store the data needed by the slow callback to generate the tooltip
    start(t); % Ask the timer to generate new text
end

function timercallback(cbo, event)

cursordata = get(cbo,'UserData');
[cbo,event] = cursordata{:};
pause(1)
txt = evalc('cbo,event,disp(get(event))');
if ~isequal(txt,getappdata(1,'lasttxt'))
    setappdata(1,'lasttxt',txt); % Store the latest text
    updateDataCursors(getappdata(1,'cursormode')); % Update the cursor so the text is displayed
end
```

Comment: This deserves a +1 for at least two reasons: first the interpretation that `ButtonUp` is being missed makes perfect sense and I had suspected as much, and second the asynchronous approach does seem attractive—this had also occurred to me, but I didn't know about the `timer` solution and had otherwise found only negative or parallel-toolbox-dependent answers to "how do you do multi-threading in Matlab?".   But it doesn't work, for reasons I've not yet been able to diagnose. On my setup, `cursormodecallback` is called but `timercallback` never is... does your `demo` work for you?

Comment: Yes—again, tested on R2012a and R2016a on Windows. So your tooltips just persistently show `Initial text`? It may help to interrogate `getappdata(1,'timer')` to see if the timer at least thinks it's running, or stepping through the callback execution with the debugger, particularly to see if the `if` blocks are ever being entered.

Comment: OK, the reason was that I actually changed the first line to `fig=100` to preserve my existing figures, and there are hardcoded `getappdata(1, ...` lines later on. I fixed this by saying `img=image;`, storing all appdata in `img` instead of `fig`,  and retrieving `img` itself with `img=get(event, 'Target');` in line 1 of `cursormodecallback` and line 3 of `timercallback`.  Now it works in the sense of updating the tooltip after 1 second, but oddly enough does not solve the original problem: even though `cusormodecallback` returns in <1ms, mouse motion is still a problem.

Comment: The mouse-motion problem goes away if I remove `pause` statements from `timercallback`. Maybe it's not time taken, but rather some side-effect of `pause` that is also coincidentally a side effect of something I do in my real callback...  There's an another problem too: in the tooltip, `event.Position` shows the *previous* click location, not the current one (I tried throwing in a `drawnow` after `updateDataCursors` but that had no effect).

Comment: Hmm, yup, as intended the `cursormodecallback` runs twice in succession, once with `get(t, 'Running')` equal to `'off'` and then once (delayed or not) with it equal to `'on'`.  But if you set `txt = 'updating...';` when it's `off`, then "updating..." is all you ever see on the tooltip: in other words, the `txt` output of the *second* callback call is not respected by Matlab's rendering engine.

Comment: Solved! Your approach works great—the `'StartDelay'` just needed to be longer. Anything <= 0.006 causes trouble; anything >= 0.007 works nicely.  I will post a full revision of your code as an extra answer but will award the bounty to you when the time comes (currently 4 hrs before I can do that).